# Obtener promedio por medio de inputs

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

estoy intentando obtener el promedio de una serie de números, tomando en cuenta el input con name y id "resultado".

Después de haber seleccionado un número se muestra el resultado, donde a su vez, el resultado se divide entre 11 para obtener el promedio y este se muestre en el respectivo input.

En pocas palabras: Dividir el input "resultado" entre 11 y que muestre el resultado en el input "promedio".

Si pudieran ayudarme les agradecería mucho.

Saludos.

```js
function Suma() {
   var ingreso1 = document.calculadora.ingreso1.value;
   var ingreso2 = document.calculadora.ingreso2.value;
   var ingreso3 = document.calculadora.ingreso3.value;
   var ingreso4 = document.calculadora.ingreso4.value;
   var ingreso5 = document.calculadora.ingreso5.value;
   var ingreso6 = document.calculadora.ingreso6.value;
   var ingreso7 = document.calculadora.ingreso7.value;
   var ingreso8 = document.calculadora.ingreso8.value;
   var ingreso9 = document.calculadora.ingreso9.value;
   var ingreso10 = document.calculadora.ingreso10.value;
   var ingreso11 = document.calculadora.ingreso11.value;
   try{
       ingreso1 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso1)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso1);
       ingreso2 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso2)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso2);
       ingreso3 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso3)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso3);
       ingreso4 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso4)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso4);
       ingreso5 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso5)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso5);
       ingreso6 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso6)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso6);
       ingreso7 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso7)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso7);
       ingreso8 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso8)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso8);
       ingreso9 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso9)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso9);
       ingreso10 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso10)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso10);
       ingreso11 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso11)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso11);
       document.calculadora.resultado.value = ingreso1+ingreso2+ingreso3+ingreso4+ingreso5+ingreso6+ingreso7+ingreso8+ingreso9+ingreso10+ingreso11;
   }
   catch(e) {}
}
```

```html
El evento onKeyUp se realiza cuando sueltas la tecla. Entonces es cuando se llama a la función Suma
<form name="calculadora">
Ingrese números:<br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso1" onchange="Suma()" min="1" max="10"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso2" onchange="Suma()" min="1" max="10"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso3" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso4" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso5" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso6" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso7" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso8" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso9" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso10" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso11" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso12" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
El resultado es:<br>
<input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado" onchange="Suma()" disabled><br>
El promedio es:<br>
<input type="text" name="promedio" id="promedio" disabled><br>

</form>
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu problema con el código que nos muestras?

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente lo que hice fue agregarle una clase `class="ingreso"` a cada elemento.
Luego recorrí todos los elementos sumando el valor de cada uno de ellos.
Después saque el promedio de ellos dividiendo por la cantidad de inputs, en este caso 11.

```js
function Suma() {
   var ingresos = document.getElementsByClassName('ingreso');
   var suma = 0;
   for(i=0; i < ingresos.length; i++){
    suma = suma + ingresos[i].value * 1;
   }
   var promedio = (suma / (ingresos.length - 1)); // Math.round si deseas redondear


   document.calculadora.resultado.value = suma;
   document.calculadora.promedio.value = promedio.toFixed(2);;

}
```

```html
El evento onKeyUp se realiza cuando sueltas la tecla. Entonces es cuando se llama a la función Suma
<form name="calculadora">
Ingrese números:<br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso1" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()" min="1" max="10"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso2" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()" min="1" max="10"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso3" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso4" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso5" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso6" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso7" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso8" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso9" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso10" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso11" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso12" class="ingreso" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
El resultado es:<br>
<input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado" onchange="Suma()" disabled><br>
El promedio es:<br>
<input type="text" name="promedio" id="promedio" disabled><br>

</form>
```

Comment: Excelente, ¿y para redondear a 2 decimales? Por ejemplo: 9.89

Comment: Modifique la respuesta para que aparezca con dos decimales solo agregue `.toFixed(2);` si la respuesta es satisfactoria, marcala como respuesta. Saludos,

Comment: Cool, si estaba bien con el ToFixed pero no sabía dónde colocarlo. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Puntúa la respuesta, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ya casi lo tienes, sólo debes hacer lo mismo que al calcular el *resultado*, pero en lugar de `document.calculadora.resultado.value`, coloca `document.calculadora.promedio.value`, pero dividiendo el total de la suma en 11.

Otra cosa, para mejor practicidad, te sugiero usar variables para almacenar resultados de operaciones aritméticas, ya que los valores se pueden manipular de forma más fácil por si en el futuro se necesita dicho valor, podría ser así:

```
try{
   .......
   .......
   .......

   var resultato = ingreso1+ingreso2+ingreso3+ingreso4+ingreso5+ingreso6+ingreso7+ingreso8+ingreso9+ingreso10+ingreso11;

   var promedio = resultado/11;

   document.calculadora.resultado.value = resultado;
   document.calculadora.promedio.value = promedio;
}
catch(e) {}
```

Comment: Cool, ya solo unas cuantas cosillas mas. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Primero en tu código html tienes un `ingreso12` que te sobra.

Por otro lado no hace falta que llames a `onChange()` en el input `resultado`.

Para escribir en pantalla usas la misma función que para el resultado `document.calculadora.promedio.value`

El promedio, no és más que la media aritmética. Por lo que sencillamente es coger el valor resultado (el cual ya suma todos los inputs) y dividrlo entre 11.

```
document.calculadora.promedio.value = document.calculadora.resultado.value/11
```

Y así tendrías el resultado final.

---

Nueva petición del usuario: "Poder redondear el resultado 2 dos números decimales".

```
.toFixed("número de decimales"); nos permite ajustar al número deseado de decimales. En nuestro caso 2.
```

```js
function Suma() {
   var ingreso1 = document.calculadora.ingreso1.value;
   var ingreso2 = document.calculadora.ingreso2.value;
   var ingreso3 = document.calculadora.ingreso3.value;
   var ingreso4 = document.calculadora.ingreso4.value;
   var ingreso5 = document.calculadora.ingreso5.value;
   var ingreso6 = document.calculadora.ingreso6.value;
   var ingreso7 = document.calculadora.ingreso7.value;
   var ingreso8 = document.calculadora.ingreso8.value;
   var ingreso9 = document.calculadora.ingreso9.value;
   var ingreso10 = document.calculadora.ingreso10.value;
   var ingreso11 = document.calculadora.ingreso11.value;
   try{
       ingreso1 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso1)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso1);
       ingreso2 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso2)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso2);
       ingreso3 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso3)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso3);
       ingreso4 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso4)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso4);
       ingreso5 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso5)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso5);
       ingreso6 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso6)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso6);
       ingreso7 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso7)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso7);
       ingreso8 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso8)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso8);
       ingreso9 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso9)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso9);
       ingreso10 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso10)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso10);
       ingreso11 = (isNaN(parseInt(ingreso11)))? 0 : parseInt(ingreso11);
       document.calculadora.resultado.value = ingreso1+ingreso2+ingreso3+ingreso4+ingreso5+ingreso6+ingreso7+ingreso8+ingreso9+ingreso10+ingreso11;
       document.calculadora.promedio.value = (document.calculadora.resultado.value/11).toFixed(2);
   }
   catch(e) {}
}
```

```html
El evento onKeyUp se realiza cuando sueltas la tecla. Entonces es cuando se llama a la función Suma
<form name="calculadora">
Ingrese números:<br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso1" onchange="Suma()" min="1" max="10"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso2" onchange="Suma()" min="1" max="10"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso3" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso4" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso5" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso6" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso7" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso8" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso9" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso10" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
<input type="number" name="ingreso11" onchange="Suma()"><br><br>
El resultado es:<br>
<input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado" disabled><br>
El promedio es:<br>
<input type="text" name="promedio" id="promedio" disabled><br>

</form>
```

Comment: Excelente, ¿y para redondear a 2 decimales? Por ejemplo: 9.89

Comment: @RazgrizEdge ya esta incluido en el código, con su pertinente explicación.

Comment: He probado el toFixed que integraste pero no me funciona

Comment: Pues fíjate a ver que tienes de diferente con mi código. Porque en el ejemplo si funciona.

Comment: Listo, faltaban unos paréntesis. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Debes marcar la respuesta que te ha servido, para que el próximo usuario que consulte este mismo problema encuentre la respuesta válida más rápidamente. Además así, la pregunta se queda como cerrada debido a que tiene una respuesta válida.